# Is there any developing activity to integrate Elementor and CiviCRM?

Tags: wordpress, extension, developer, user-experience, base-page

Probably many of you know [Elementor](https://elementor.com/), a powerful and high diffused page builder for the **WordPress** world.

Elementor works having widgets, which realize tasks in shaping, db connections and dynamic fields managing in wordpress pages. There is a [platform for developers](https://elementor.com/features/development/) to build addons and extensions, and many of them are going out in the market, free and not.

Is there anybody who is working to integrate CiviCRM  and Elementor for some tasks?

Comment: This seems like a question better asked in the WordPress channel on https://chat.civicrm.org - if someone's working on it, they'll know.

Comment: I post it there now

Comment: It could be great to build some Elementor widgets to integrate CiviCRM contacts, events, campaigns and others elements to create very attractive pages and dashboards.